# Laravel: Model functions called inside view

Tags: php, laravel, function, view, model

Am I able to create a boolean function that returns me for example true if person is a woman and false if person is a man?

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Patient extends Model
{
   public $fillable = ['name', 'surname', 'code'];
   public function queque(){
         return $this->hasMany(Queque::class);
   }
   public function gender(){
        if([GET CODE FROM THIS SPECIFIC USER][8] % 2 == 0){ //in my country 9th number od code is used to differ between genders
          return false; //man
     } else{
          return true; //woman
     }
   }
}
```

I want it to be used **in view**. So when i use it like `{{$patient->gender}}` it returns 0 or 1. Is it even possible? I know about **query scopes but they are useless in view**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to use it directly from your model instead of implementing it within your controller and then pass it to your view file?

Comment: I want to use it inside my view.

Comment: I want to somehow automate process of checking 9th number in "code" and checking if it's divisible by 2

Comment: So i can do something like
`@if($patient->gender)
man
@endif`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may pass your patient code as a parameter :

```
public static function gender($patientCode) {

if($patientCode % 2 == 0)
// .....
```

then call it within your view file as follows by passing your code to your method:

```
{{ App\Patient::gender($patient->code); }}
```

Comment: Let's say I pass to my view a patient with it 1:
  $patient = Patient::find(1);
And then I how can i specify what gender is he?
How can i fullfill the space "GET CODE FROM THIS SPECIFIC USER" inside my model?

Comment: do you mean that this `GET CODE FROM THIS SPECIFIC USER` is an user input ?

Comment: Function inside my model. How can i get a field from database that's equal to `code`. So i can actually check the gender?

Comment: so you are asking about fetching data from db ? not passing it to your view files?

Comment: i am passing user into view. ONE user. I want to know what gender is he. How can i accomplish this knowing that i can get his gender only by CODE column inside mysql. IF 9th number of CODE is divisible by 2 then he's a man. How can i possibly access his gender from view. By doing something like $patient->gender. I think it's connected to accessors but i dont't know how to do it properly.

Comment: I can do it easilly in controller but i don't want to pass every data like this. It's tedious. I wanted to automate this somehow